# gazebo 2.2.2 with ros hydro from source and TurtleBot

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS-Hydro-Desktop-Full from source in April this year on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander).  During the install, the script installed `Gazebo 2.2.2` using APT-GET. The script also installed `gazebo_ros_pkgs 2.3.5`.  Up until now, everything's been working great, including some simple Gazebo stuff I started playing with.
But now I would like to get Gazebo running with ROS, and I understand that Hydro is intended to work with Gazebo 1.9, but I have 2.2.2, and I'm not sure what to do?

I decided I would try working through the [turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Installation) page, but in step 4.3 "rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y" fails with the following errors:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
yocs_virtual_sensor: No definition of [rospy_message_converter] for OS version [saucy]
turtlebot_teleop: No definition of [joy] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_random_walker: No definition of [ecl_threads] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_node: No definition of [ecl_threads] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_safety_controller: No definition of [ecl_threads] for OS version [saucy]
turtlebot_core_apps: No definition of [map_store] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_auto_docking: No definition of [ecl_linear_algebra] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_dock_drive: No definition of [ecl_linear_algebra] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_keyop: No definition of [ecl_time] for OS version [saucy]
turtlebot_gazebo: No definition of [depthimage_to_laserscan] for OS version [saucy]
yocs_diff_drive_pose_controller: No definition of [ecl_threads] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_ftdi: No definition of [ecl_command_line] for OS version [saucy]
yocs_velocity_smoother: No definition of [ecl_threads] for OS version [saucy]
turtlebot_bringup: No definition of [depthimage_to_laserscan] for OS version [saucy]
kobuki_driver: No definition of [ecl_command_line] for OS version [saucy]
```

The errors seem to indicate that my problem has to do with the version of Ubuntu I have rather than my version of Gazebo.
Since Hydro was released for 13.10, and the tutorial refers to Hydro, the errors don't quite make sense.  Unless it has to do with the `gazebo_ros_pkgs` that I have installed.

I've invested a lot of time and download bandwidth building the existing install and would prefer to somehow fix this up with an incremental solution.  If this possible?

Since Gazebo 2.2.2 was actually installed using APT-GET, can I remove the package and install 1.9 instead?  And I can delete  `gazebo_ros_pkgs` I have and download the version that normally comes with 1.9.

Will this fix the problem?

Cheers,
Nap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195241/gazebo-2.2.2-with-ros-hydro-from-source-and-turtlebot/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you should be able to remove the debian packages installed by apt for gazebo 2.2 and the corresponding new gazebo_ros_pkgs and install the older ones.

Anything built on top of them will need to be rebuilt.

Your rosdep errors are a separate issue. I would guess that you are not in an environment that as the ROSDISTRO envrionment variable set to `hydro` so it does not know to look for those packages from hydro. This is usually done by sourcing /opt/ros/hydro/setup/bash `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-10-24**:
Thanks for that, I will try it.  I have `source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash` in my .bashrc. but no, ROSDISTRO is not set.  I'll add that export to my .bashrc file.